# Can't make post request using params as dictionary with Swift 4 & Alamofire

Tags: swift, post, request, alamofire

I'm trying to learn to call API with/without library. But the problem here confuses me.

I have params like this:

```
let parameters: [String:String] =
            ["key":"MY_KEY" ,
             "q":sourceText,
             "source": sourceLanguage),
             "target": target)]

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [ "Content-type": "application/json"]
```

I make a post call like this:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
                .responseJSON{ response in
                    guard response.result.error == nil else {
                        print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
                        print(response.result.error!)
                        return
                    }
                    // make sure we got some JSON since that's what we expect
                    guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
                        print("didn't get todo object as JSON from API")
                        print("Error: \(response.result.error)")
                        return
                    }
```

By this I get an error 403, saying that I do not have a valid API key (I tested the key with postman, and **it is okay**).

After many efforts, I have to change the code like this

```
let stringparams = "key=MY_KEY&q=\(sourceText)&source=\(sourceLanguage)&target=\(target)"
request.httpBody = stringparams.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

and using this: Alamofire.request(request)
it works!
I'm using Google Cloud Translation api. And the web use a REST api as said here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate

**So why can't I use params as dictionary, but using the string (like formdata) will work here?**

My guess is Alamofire didn't make the right BODY for the request from the parameters because other arguments is okay. But I don't know why.
And I think Google should accept a json params as they mentioned, in stead of using form data? I did try the original method, but it didn't work with JSON.

Comment: The `Alamofire.request` method has the parameter `encoding`, which you may need to customise if you have a non-standard way of passing parameters to your request (which it seems like you do).

Comment: In this version I forgot that I deleted the encoding: JSONEncoding.default. But it didn't work, neither.

Earlier it is like this:
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)

Comment: You may have to create your own implementation of `ParameterEncoding`.

Comment: @GuyKogus Sorry. Can you explain to me how to implement the param encoding here? I thought I have to provide the params as exactly as required in the Alamofire request method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what actually works for you it looks like you need to encode the parameters in the same style as a query. Try this:

```
struct ParameterQueryEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
        request.httpBody = parameters?
            .map { "\($0)=\($1)" }
            .joined(separator: "&")
            .data(using: .utf8)
        return request
    }
}
```

You should then be able to perform the original call that you had before:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString,
                  method: HTTPMethod.post,
                  parameters: parameters,
                  encoding: ParameterQueryEncoding(),
                  headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont know how to update my question but your solution only works if I change the headers to: 
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [ "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
Then I remove the headers. Put in the header argument as: [:]. It also works. 
Then in my last try, I change the encoding to URLEncoding.default. It works, too. No need to customise the encoding. The problem is with the header. Just don't know when we need to put in the headers? And how it works behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using JSON encoding. Make sure you have removed ) from dictionary.

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried this one and it doesnot work. The ) is a typo when I input the question here.